# Variable names as Input in an R Function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several numeric variables along with factors. I wish to run over the numeric variables and replace the negative values to missing. I couldn't do that.

My alternative idea was to write a function that gets a dataframe and a variable, and does it. It didn't work either.

My code is:

```
NegativeToMissing = function(df,var)
{
  df$var[df$var < 0] = NA
}

Error in $<-.data.frame(`*tmp*`, "var", value = logical(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 40
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: Read `?Extract`. I think what you need in there is `df[[var]][ df[[var]] < 0 ] <- NA`. When you use `df$var`, it expects a column named `var` in the frame, which is not the case. To reference it *indirectly*, the only method is with `[` (which should return a single-column frame) or `[[` (which always returns a vector).

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with some dummy data.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(-1, 1, 2, 0, -3),
                  col2 = 1:5,
                  col3 = LETTERS[1:5])
df1
#  col1 col2 col3
#1   -1    1    A
#2    1    2    B
#3    2    3    C
#4    0    4    D
#5   -3    5    E
```

Now find columns that are numeric

```
numeric_cols <- sapply(df1, is.numeric)
```

And replace negative values

```
df1[numeric_cols] <- lapply(df1[numeric_cols], function(x) replace(x, x < 0 , NA))
df1
#  col1 col2 col3
#1   NA    1    A
#2    1    2    B
#3    2    3    C
#4    0    4    D
#5   NA    5    E
```

---

You could also do

```
df1[df1 < 0] <- NA
```

Comment: I understand why you used sapply at first, but why lapply later. Doesn't it return a list ?

Comment: @user2899944 Yes. A data.frame is a list too (with elements of equal length) so we can use `lapply` here to replace the values of the `numeric_cols`. But you could also use `sapply` or `vapply` instead.

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, we can make use of `mutate_if`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(replace(., . < 0, NA)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to change only one selected variable a solution with`dplyr` would be to use [non-standard evaluation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html):

```
library(dplyr)
NegativeToMissing <- function(df, var) {
  quo_var = quo_name(var)
  df %>% 
    mutate(!!quo_var := ifelse(!!var < 0, NA, !!var))

}

NegativeToMissing(data, var=quo(val1)) # use quo() function without ""
#   val1 val2
# 1    1    1
# 2   NA    2
# 3    2    3
```

Data used:

```
data <- data.frame(val1 = c(1, -1, 2),
                   val2 = 1:3)
data
#   val1 val2
# 1    1    1
# 2   -1    2
# 3    2    3
```